# vue.js save data in a new array with submit and display it in another table

Tags: arrays, submit, vue.js

I need to make 2 tables in which I can select data in one table and with submit show it in another table. Then with remove button to put it back to the first table. This is what I came up with so far. Can anyone assist me please?

```
 <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/morka/65w7Lc96/embed/"></script>
  https://jsfiddle.net/morka/65w7Lc96/
```

Comment: Possible for you to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/7o4k0gf2/) of it?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems in your `addItems`  function which is currently returning true or false, instead of adding items actually. You need to change your `addItems` function like following:

```
    addItems: function(){
            this.newItems = this.selected;
    }
```

Also as you are just pushing names in `this.selected`, you have to remove `.name` when rendering table of `newItems`. You can change the code to by pushing the object in `this.selected` to access name ini `newItems`.

Check the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65w7Lc96/4/).